# How to get Result 1 for all user_ids that at least one time have source as paid

Tags: sql, postgresql

How to get `Result=1` for all `user_ids` that at least one time have source as paid. I mean not just for one row where `source=paid`, but for all rows for this `user_id`.

Result column does not exist in the table! We should get it somehow using the code!

```
Row Table
source  session_number  user_id
NULL    1                12345  
NULL    2                12345  
NULL    3                12345  
NULL    4                12345  
NULL    1                67890  
paid    2                67890  
NULL    3                67890
```

```
Desired Table
source  session_number  user_id result
NULL    1                12345  0
NULL    2                12345  0
NULL    3                12345  0
NULL    4                12345  0
NULL    1                67890  1
paid    2                67890  1
NULL    3                67890  1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want a window function.  It would seem to be:

```
select t.*,
       max(case when source = 'paid' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by userid) as result
from t;
```

In Postgres, you can return a boolean as:

```
select t.*,
       bool_or(source = 'paid') over (partition by userid) as result
from t;
```

Answer (score 0):

use exists

```
select a.* from table_name a
where exists( select 1 from table_name b where a.userid=b.userid
                              and b.source='paid')
and result=1
```

Comment: Result column does not exist in the table! We should get it somehow using the code!

Answer (score 0):

With subquery

```
SELECT  *, 
        CASE 
            WHEN user_id IN 
              (
                SELECT user_id 
                FROM table_name
                WHERE source = 'paid'
              ) 
            THEN 1 
            ELSE 0 
         END AS result
FROM table_name
```

Comment: Result column does not exist in the table! We should get it somehow using the code!

Comment: Please check my amended answer, hope it helps :)